# Piwik on shared phpfog

Tags: cloud-hosting, matomo

Is it possible to run Piwik as an app on PHPfog's free shared Cloud hosting?

There are several restricitons on PHPFog shared Cloud like 48MB Memory Limits or Disabled Functions like "file_get_contents for remote URLS".
Look here for a full list: http://docs.phpfog.com/index.php/features/article/shared_vs_dedicated

Has somebody already tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Piwik a while ago actually.  You can get it off the ground for sure but full functionality isn't available till you upgrade to a dedicated plan.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try running a [Piwik Amazon Machine Image directly](http://bitnami.org/stack/piwik#cloudImage) using BitNami. If you combine it with the AWS free tier, you can get basically a free Piwik server  (Disclaimer, I am one of the BitNami developers)